# JS - Efficient way to iterate throught lists inside lists

Tags: javascript, loops

What is the most efficient algorithm to find items inside another list? Let me try to write an example:

- I have the following structure:

  - Employers: `[{"id": 1, "skill": 10},{"id": 2, "skill": 90}];`
  - Customers: `[{"id": 12, "mood": 5},{"id": 2, "mood": 70}]`.

That information is represented by an Array:

- Employers array: `[[1, 10], [2, 90]]`;
- Customers array: `[[12, 5], [2, 70]]`.

In my case, employers can only interact with customers that has an *mood* lower than his *skill*. The return of my function should be the employer with highest interaction count.

I've wrote a function that can do this rule but it's pretty slow when I have a big number of employers or customers - it took more than 7 seconds to finish.

```
function countEmployersByMoodAtt(operatos, customers) {
    let distribution = [];
    //sort operators by skill so I can guarantee that big skills won't come first
    operatos.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);

    operatos.forEach(cs => {
        let skill = cs[1];        
        //map to extract only the customer id
        let customersAvailable = customers
            .filter(customer => customer[1] <= skill)
            .map(x => x[0]);
        //convert to set because i've wrote it's fast
        let customerAvSet = new Set(customersAvailable);
        //include on result list
        distribution.push([cs[0], customersAvailable.length]);
        //remove customers already assigned
        customers = customers.filter(([cs]) => !customerAvSet.has(cs));
    });
    //sort to first position be hightest score    
    distribution.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

    //return operator
    return distribution[0][0];    
}
```

An example input is:

- `operators = [[1, 60], [3, 90]];`
- `customers = [[1, 30], [1, 40], [1, 60], [1, 70]];`

Output should be 1.

Main rule: can't get the highest operator skill and put all on it. I need to balance between operators - I need to iterate from lower skill to higher one.

Any tip on how can I can optimize it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Output should be 1` Why? Doesn't the operator with an ID of 3 and a skill of 90 have the ability to interact with all `customers` (one more than the first operator with ID 1)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance If i put all customers on operator with an ID 3, he will be over estimated. I need to balance it, so that't why I order operators.

Comment: just a side question, why not use the objects as data instead of nonspeaking arrays? please supply a bigger data set for testing and the result as well. actually it is like looking through a keyhole into an open watch for a part which is under some otherparts hidden in the dark. please turn the lights on.

Comment: @NinaScholz its an exercise. Can't use objects like json

Comment: nevertheless, you could add some data. please see edit of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should run in the order of `O(c*o)` where `c` is customer count and `o` is operator count.

```js
  var o = [[1, 60], [3, 90]];
  var c = [[1, 30], [1, 40], [1, 60], [1, 70]];

  function countEmployersByMoodAtt(operatos, customers) {
  var cInt = [];
  var gInt = {};
  var i, j;
  var opIndex;

  for (i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    // find lowest possible operator to interact with
    opIndex = null;
    for (j = operatos.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (operatos[j][1] < customers[i][1]) {
        // can't interact. continue to next operator
        continue;
      }

      if (opIndex !== null) {
        if (operatos[j][1] < operatos[opIndex][1]) {
          opIndex = j;
        }
      } else {
        opIndex = j;
      }
    }

    if (opIndex === null) {
      cInt.push(null);
    } else {
      cInt.push(operatos[opIndex][0]);
    }
  }


  for (i = 0; i < cInt.length; i++) {
    if (gInt[cInt[i]] === undefined) {
      gInt[cInt[i]] = 0;
    }

    gInt[cInt[i]] += 1;
  }

  var maxId = null, maxOp = 0;
  var keys = Object.keys(gInt);

  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (gInt[keys[i]] > maxOp) {
      maxId = keys[i];
      maxOp = gInt[keys[i]];
    }
  }

  return maxId;
}

console.log(countEmployersByMoodAtt(o, c));
```

Benchmark:

```js
var o = [];
var c = [];

for (var k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
  o.push([k + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)]);
  c.push([k + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)]);
}

function myCountEmployersByMoodAtt(operatos, customers) {
  var cInt = [];
  var gInt = {};
  var i, j;
  var opIndex;

  for (i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    // find lowest possible operator to interact with
    opIndex = null;
    for (j = operatos.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (operatos[j][1] < customers[i][1]) {
        // can't interact. continue to next operator
        continue;
      }

      if (opIndex !== null) {
        if (operatos[j][1] < operatos[opIndex][1]) {
          opIndex = j;
        }
      } else {
        opIndex = j;
      }
    }

    if (opIndex === null) {
      cInt.push(null);
    } else {
      cInt.push(operatos[opIndex][0]);
    }
  }


  for (i = 0; i < cInt.length; i++) {
    if (gInt[cInt[i]] === undefined) {
      gInt[cInt[i]] = 0;
    }

    gInt[cInt[i]] += 1;
  }

  var maxId = null, maxOp = 0;
  var keys = Object.keys(gInt);

  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (gInt[keys[i]] > maxOp) {
      maxId = keys[i];
      maxOp = gInt[keys[i]];
    }
  }

  return maxId;
}

function yourCountEmployersByMoodAtt(operatos, customers) {
  let distribution = [];
  //sort operators by skill so I can guarantee that big skills won't come first
  operatos.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);

  operatos.forEach(cs => {
    let skill = cs[1];
    //map to extract only the customer id
    let customersAvailable = customers
      .filter(customer => customer[1] <= skill)
      .map(x => x[0]);
    //convert to set because i've wrote it's fast
    let customerAvSet = new Set(customersAvailable);
    //include on result list
    distribution.push([cs[0], customersAvailable.length]);
    //remove customers already assigned
    customers = customers.filter(([cs]) => !customerAvSet.has(cs));
  });
  //sort to first position be hightest score
  distribution.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

  //return operator
  return distribution[0][0];
}

var t0 = performance.now();
console.log('MyResult: ' + myCountEmployersByMoodAtt(o, c));
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log('Your result: ' + yourCountEmployersByMoodAtt(o, c));
var t2 = performance.now();
console.log('My time: ' + (t1 - t0));
console.log('Your time: ' + (t2 - t1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your question was unclear, but reading through the code it makes enough sense. The employers can interact with the customers with a mood lower than their skill, but they can't interact with a customer that another employee of lower skill can interact with as well. Let's solve that.

For one, it makes very little sense to filter, then copy the result of that into a set, then run another filter where you filter out everything that you just filtered. Sounds like a mess, right? It is.

Instead, just create your set initially with all the customers. Then run a forEach, and delete the customers from the set who can be served by the lowest skill worker, incrementing a counter for every customer you do this for. You didn't actually send the customer IDs along with the distribution so it makes no sense to hold on to customer IDs at all.

Algorithm would be something like this:
Sort employees and customers according to skill and mood.
Create a counter variable.
Iterate through customers. 
For each customer, if their mood < current employee's skill, increment the counter. 
If not, store the count inside your distribution, along with the current employee ID. Then go to the next employee ID.

Repeat. Didn't actually get a chance to use a set. I don't think they're ordered. This works fine though and you can do it in one pass after sorting.

```
function countEmployersByMoodAtt(operators, customers) {
  console.log("Sorting operators.");
  operators.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
  console.log("Sorting customers");
  customers.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
  console.log("Starting processing.");

  let distribution = [];
  let opIndex = 0;
  let customersServed = 0;
  let bestEmployeeID;
  let mostServed = -1;
  let skill = operators[opIndex][1];

  for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; ++i) {
    let mood = customers[i][1];
    if (mood < skill) 
      ++customersServed;
    else {
      // check if new record.
      if (customersServed > mostServed) {
        mostServed = customersServed;
        bestEmployeeID = operators[opIndex][0];
        customersServed = 1; // this will count toward the employee found in while() loop.
      }
      // find next qualified employee.
      while (mood > skill && ++opIndex < operators.length) {
        skill = operators[opIndex][1];
      }
      // no employees can serve customer.
      if (opIndex >= operators.length) {
        console.log("No employees skilled enough for remaining customers.")
        return [bestEmployeeID, mostServed];
      }
    }
  }
  // need to do this one more time for the last set of customers. 
  // because 'else' case won't run if customer is served adequately.
  // and if a new employee is selected for the last customer, bestEmployee won't be set.
  if (customersServed > mostServed) {
    mostServed = customersServed;
    bestEmployeeID = operators[opIndex[0]];
  }
  return [bestEmployeeID, mostServed];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an array with skills sorted descending and iterate customers which iterates counter array and check the mood `m`.

If `m` is smaller than skill, then increment count, otherwise exit the inner loop.

`counter` contains the count for each skill level.

```js
var employers = [[1, 10], [2, 90]],
    customers = [[12, 5], [2, 70]],
    counter = employers.map(([, v]) => [v, 0]).sort(([a], [b]) => b - a);
    
customers.forEach(([m]) => counter.every(a => m < a[0] && ++a[1]));

console.log(counter);
```